# Pyinstaller not finding hook

Tags: python, hook, pyinstaller

I'm using the latest version of pyinstaller and when I run it I get the following error message:

```
9007 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
kg_resources.DistributionNotFound: 
The 'cryptography' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I have checked and the cryptography distribution is definitely available, but for some reason pyinstaller doesn't find it. Is there a way to edit the spec file to make it work?

Interestingly, when I search for the hook-cryptography I find a .py file which is  in the pyinstaller/hooks folder.

Comment: So I was the last one to touch that hook.  Are you using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography/1.8.1?

Comment: It works with certain versions but doesn't with others. Unfortunately in my case I have to use a specific version that seems I compatible. What would you suggest to solve this error? What could be the reason for not working?

Comment: The various reasons for not working are legion.  Crypto includes third party libs in various hard to figure out ways.  If you must support a specific version, you should use your own hook as pyinstaller will generally only support the latest version of a lib. Which version of crypto are you using?  Maybe I can gin something up.

Comment: It's version 1.7.1 and strangely enough, sometimes the compilation with pyinstaller works, and sometimes it doesn't (it never works on teamcity)

Comment: I don't think the module is actually needed. Could I simply exclude it?